# I using syncfusion table in that i am struck download report

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function downloadOfflineReport(rowData) {
    let file_type = rowData.file_type
    let trans_id = rowData.trans_id
    let feature_code = rowData.feature_code
    let name = getDescription(rowData.feature_code)

    console.log("click trans_id", trans_id); // {"$oid": "65673555e4b065ec1afa1bec"}

}



return (
    <CommonLayout isLoading={loading}>
        <div className="view-reports-wrapper">
            <div className="oneline-row j-space-between a-center px-2">
                <div className="font font-header py-2">Download Reports</div>
            </div>
            <GridComponent
                dataSource={data} // Set the data source
                allowPaging={true}
                pageSettings={{ pageSize: pageSize, pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] }} // Enable paging
                allowSorting={true}
                allowFiltering={false}
                gridLines={"None"}
                ref={(g) => (grid = g)}
                dataStateChange={dataStateChange}
            >
                <ColumnsDirective>
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='_id'
                        headerText='Reference Code'
                        width='60'
                        textAlign="right"
                        headerTextAlign="Center"

                    />
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='updtd_dt'
                        headerText='Date'
                        width='60'
                        textAlign="left"
                        headerTextAlign="Center"
                        template={(data) => formatDate(data?.updtd_dt)}
                        customAttributes={{ class: 'left-padded-column' }}

                    />
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='crtd_dt'
                        headerText='Executed Date'
                        width='60'
                        textAlign="left"
                        headerTextAlign="Center"
                        template={(data) => formatDate(data?.crtd_dt)}
                        customAttributes={{ class: 'left-padded-column' }}
                    />

                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='feature_code'
                        headerText='Description'
                        width='70'
                        textAlign="left"
                        headerTextAlign="Center"
                        template={(data) => getDescription(data?.feature_code)}
                        customAttributes={{ class: 'left-padded-column' }}

                    />
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='file_type'
                        headerText='File type'
                        width='70'
                        textAlign="left"
                        headerTextAlign="Center"
                        customAttributes={{ class: 'left-padded-column' }}

                    />
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='status_desc'
                        headerText='Status'
                        width='50'
                        textAlign="left"
                        template={(data) => {
                            return <GridStatusTemplate status={data?.status} statusDesc={getStatusDes(data?.status === 3002 ? 3005 : data?.status)} />
                        }}
                        headerTextAlign={"Center"}
                        customAttributes={{ class: 'left-padded-column' }}


                    />
                    <ColumnDirective
                        field='actions'
                        width='50'
                        headerText='Actions'
                        template={(data) => {
                            return <ReportActionsDropdown
                                rowData={data}
                                status={data?.status}
                                downloadOfflineReport={downloadOfflineReport}
                            />
                        }}
                        textAlign="Center"
                        allowFiltering={false}
                        headerTextAlign={"Center"}
                    // filterTemplate={GridEmptyTemplate}
                    />
                </ColumnsDirective>
                <Inject services={[Page, Sort]} />
            </GridComponent>
        </div>
    </CommonLayout>
)
```

In the `DownloadReports` code, Syncfusion library is used to implement a table. There's an issue in the `downloadOfflineReport` function, triggered on row action. The `rowData` contains a `trans_id` in the format: `{"$oid": "65673555e4b065ec1afa1bec"}`.

The objective is to query MongoDB's `fs.chunks` collection using the `files_id` field: 'db.getCollection('fs.chunks').find({"files_id" : ObjectId("65673555e4b065ec1afa1bec")})'

The expected database response is:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("655ef8dbe4b0883139390433"),
    "files_id": ObjectId("655ef8dbe4b0883139390432"),
    "n": 0,
    "data": { "$binary": "UEsDBBQACAgIAPdjd1cAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl"}
}

here i cant be use Node.js for backend how it can be possible in react js
```